# Program crashes even with try and catch statements

Tags: java

one problem I noticed is that the program crashes if you enter non digits even though there is a catch statement. can someone help me out? I can't seem to find the problem.

Can you also explain what I'm doing wrong and why it's wrong? Thank you in advance.

//previous code had an issue while I was creating a new scanner. it's correct now.

```
import java.util.*;

public class HighLow {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numberOfAttempts = 0;

    System.out.println("WIN THE THREE ROUNDS TO WIN THE GAME!.");

    int theNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);

    System.out.println("Round 1: I am thinking of a number between" + "\n" + "1 and 10, can you guess the number in " + "\n" + "less than 3 attempts?");    

    System.out.println("Type a number below and press enter.");

    int guess = 0;

    do {

      try {

        guess = scan.nextInt();

        if (guess != theNumber) {

          if (guess < theNumber) {

            System.out.println("Sorry " + guess + " is too low, please try again");

          }else if (guess > theNumber) {

            System.out.println("Sorry " + guess + " is too high, please try again." );

          }
          numberOfAttempts = numberOfAttempts + 1;

        }else {
          System.out.println(guess + " is the correct answer. You got it on" + "\n" + "attempt number " + (numberOfAttempts  + 1)  + ". Proceeding to round 2.");

          theNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);

          System.out.println("\n" + "Round 2: I am thinking of a number between " + "\n" + "1 and 100, can you guess the number in " + "\n" + "less than 6 attempts?");

          numberOfAttempts = 0;

          int secondRoundGuess = 0;

      do {

          try {

            secondRoundGuess = scan.nextInt();

          if (secondRoundGuess != theNumber) {

            if (secondRoundGuess < theNumber) {

              System.out.println("Sorry " + secondRoundGuess + " is too low, please try again");

            }else{

              System.out.println("Sorry " + secondRoundGuess + " is too high, please try again");  

            }

            numberOfAttempts = numberOfAttempts + 1;
          }

          else {
            System.out.println(secondRoundGuess + " is the correct answer. You got it on " + "\n" + "attempt number " + (numberOfAttempts + 1) + "." + "\n" + "Proceeding to round 3.");

            System.out.println("\n" + "Round 3: I am thinking of a number between " + "\n" + "1 and 1000, can you guess the number in " + "\n" + "less than 10 attempts?");

            theNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 1000 + 1);

            numberOfAttempts = 0;
            int thirdRoundGuess = 0;

            do {

            try {

              thirdRoundGuess = scan.nextInt();

              if (thirdRoundGuess != theNumber) {              

                if (thirdRoundGuess < theNumber) {

                  System.out.println("Sorry " + thirdRoundGuess + " is too low, please try again");                    

                }else {

                  System.out.println("Sorry " + thirdRoundGuess + " is too high, please try again");

                }

                numberOfAttempts = numberOfAttempts + 1;

              }else{
                System.out.println(thirdRoundGuess + " is the correct answer.");

                System.out.println("You won the game, you are a badass." + "\n" + "I made this game and I cant even beat " + "\n" + "level 3.");

                System.out.println("I am a newbie at programming and it's my " + "\n" + "fourth month on this java journey ." + "\n" + "I am looking for fellow newbies  who are willing " + "\n" + "to learn and grow together (or advanced programmers " + "\n" + "who will not get annoyed by teaching newbies)."  + "\n" + "If you get to this point in the game " + "\n" + "and see this message, hit me up via direct " + "\n" + "messaging, lets create a group where we can learn " + "\n" + "and grow together.");

              }

            }catch(Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Please enter a number.");

              thirdRoundGuess = scan.nextInt();
            }

            }while(numberOfAttempts != 10);
            System.out.println("Game over, you were so close. Try again");

          }

          }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number.");

            secondRoundGuess = scan.nextInt();

          }

      }while(numberOfAttempts != 6);

      System.out.println("Game Over. Try again?");

        }

      }catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number.");

        guess = scan.nextInt();
      }

    }while (numberOfAttempts != 3);

    System.out.println("Game Over. Try again?");

    scan.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste here the error messages you see?

Comment: `Scanner scan = newScanner(System.in);` doesn't look right. Are you sure that this is your current code you are *executing*?

Comment: So... if you look at the log, you should find the word `Exception` someplace. That line will list a line number which corresponds to a line in your program. Identify that line, and that's your problem. If you don't understand the exception, post the line here (the line, not the line number -- we can't see your text editor from here). Read the Stack Overflow [help file](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which will help you ask good questions that receive good answers.

Comment: In your catch statement, it would be good to add a line 'e.printStackTrace()' to find the error.

Comment: @Pshemo Yes, you're right. I must have missed that when I was checking for misplaced spaces, on my IDE, it's fine.

Comment: In that case please [edit] your question and correct that mistake. Lets not introduce to question problems unrelated to what you want to ask about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is using `scan.nextInt()` inside the `catch` block. What is happening is `guess = scan.nextInt();` just below the `try` is throwing an exception for non-integer input and the control enters the catch block where it encounters `guess = scan.nextInt();` again which tries to consume the <kbd>Enter</kbd> from the last input causing the program to crash as <kbd>Enter</kbd> is not an `int`.

### How to get rid of it?

You need to make two changes to get rid of the problem:

**A.** Use `guess = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());` in which `scan.nextLine()` will also consume <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

**B.** Comment out the line, `guess = scan.nextInt();` as shown below:

```
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number.");
    //guess = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you're such an awesome person. Your suggestion worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is the exception stack trace you get when you run the code:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
    at HighLow.main(HighLow.java:137)
```

When you handle the exception first time the user types in a non-numeric value, the exception gets handled below:

```java
catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number.");

    guess = scan.nextInt();
}
```

When it reaches `guess = scan.nextInt();`, the previous non-numeric value is still present in the scanner. And when it tries to get an integer out of the scanner when it has a non-numeric value, it throws another `InputMismatchException` inside `catch` that is not handled.